# How much am I supposed to tilt the controller?

Tags: heavy-rain

This question comes in relation to a couple trophies I am completely stuck on in Heavy Rain:

- **Kamikaze**
  The Bear - Take the best route on the highway
- **I'm not Scared!**
  Twins - Follow your brother without making any mistakes

These would both be generally easy except for the fact they both involve tilt commands with the controller, which neither of my controllers seem to want to do. I have tried these chapters many, many times (around 50 now) and I can get all the ordinary left, right, X, and O moves down perfectly, no problem. But it only ever seems to recognize around 50% of any tilt commands I have to do. I have tried everything to do these, tilting it up at a 90 degree angle to just tilting it slightly. It seems like it sometimes just *doesn't want to recognize* that I tilted the controller.

Is there some specific way I'm supposed to tilt the controller to get the game to recognize that I did? I mean, I went as far as actually pausing the game after each successful command so that I could level the controller and tilt again, still with no success. Keep in mind, I've tried this with two separate controllers, one which I use frequently, and the other which is just a backup that I've only ever used a few times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On The Bear mission, my biggest recommendation is to hold the controller as if you're holding the wheel of a car, with the buttons facing you, and tilting the wheel left and right like you would turn a wheel.

On the mission to follow your brother, I assume you're having problems with the balancing parts, would recommend holding the controller in front of you, face buttons facing the ceiling, and tilting left and right like you would tilt a tray. It shouldn't require too much tilting. Don't follow in the animation in the icon but follow the character's hands, tilting the control as to keep them leveled.

Hope these tips help.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: I had a ton of trouble with the car-style tilts as well.  Here's the thing, I was moving the controller in a smooth motion when really you just have to move it 90° sideways and LEAVE IT THERE.